# Multistore with subfolders - Including language code before store group in URL

Tags: multistore, url-rewrite, store-view, base-url

I have a client who needs to include a language code before the store group in the URL. For example, the current setup is:

```
example.com/store1
example.com/store2
```

There are two subfolders in the root of the site named store1 and store2. Is it possible to include a lang code (i.e. fr, de, en) before the /store1 section of the URL?

`example.com/en/store1`

I understand that it would be best to use store codes, but seeing as we have two store groups, both needing "en", it wouldn't be possible due to it needing to be unique.

Any help would be appreciated!